# Как вывести символы разных цветов?

Tags: java, android, color

Если коротко, то нужно поменять цвет отдельных символов, а не цвет всей строки. Например, все буквы Р красные

Я хочу сделать приложение, которое будет менять в тексте, полученным с EditText, цвет некоторых букв, и текст должен отобразиться уже в TextView с разными цветами после нажатия кнопки. Например, после введения в input строки "Hello World!" чтобы все l стали красного цвета.

```
public void onClick(View v) {
if (v.getId()==_ok_button.getId()){


    String text=input_TextBox.getText().toString();

    output_TextView.setText(text);

}
```

Как дополнить код, чтобы это осуществить?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Я не могу додуматься, как поменять цвет отдельных символов в строке и вывести всю строку с измененными символами

Comment: если бы у меня возникла такая задача, то я бы начал ее решение с запроса в гугул типа "android set color letter" или вроде того. Попробуй и ты с этого начать....

Comment: ничего дельного не выводит, только обьясняют как поменять текст всего текста или цвет символа уже известного текста, а мне нужно менять цвета некоторых букв в написанной пользователем строке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Что использовать (примерный вид кода)**:

Думаю, что тут пригодится работа с текстом или его частями как с html разметкой:

```
String text=input_TextBox.getText().toString();
String styledText = "<font color='red'>" + text +  "</font>";
output_TextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(styledText), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);
```

**Как использовать fromHtml**:

Так как Html.fromHtml стал `deprecated` следует использовать такой метод:

```
HtmlCompat.fromHtml(styledText, HtmlCompat.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
```

Пример [снипета](https://code.pixplicity.com/android/common/html-compat/) для HtmlCompat:

```
package com.pixplicity.example.utils;

import android.text.Html;
import android.text.Spanned;

public final class HtmlCompat {
    public static Spanned fromHtml(String source) {
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            return Html.fromHtml(source, Html.FROM_HTML_MODE_LEGACY);
        } else {
            //noinspection deprecation
            return Html.fromHtml(source);
        }
    }
}
```

**Как форматировать цвет**:

Чтобы поменять цвет символов в строке следует воспользоваться заменой с регулярными выражениями:

```
  String str = "Hello World!";
  str = str.replaceAll("(l)", "<font color='red'>$1</font>");
  System.out.println(str);
```

К примеру этот код выведет строку:

```
He<font color='red'>l</font><font color='red'>l</font>o Wor<font color='red'>l</font>d!
```

Тут все буквы `l` будут красными, запустите снипет снизу чтобы увидеть примерный вид:

```html
He<font color='red'>l</font><font color='red'>l</font>o Wor<font color='red'>l</font>d!
```

**Вариант для WebView:**

loadData

```
String base64 = android.util.Base64.encodeToString(styledText
  .getBytes("UTF-8"), android.util.Base64.DEFAULT);

webView.loadData(base64, "text/html; charset=utf-8", "base64");
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139387/discussion-on-answer-by-daniil-loban-----).